# Could you help me Explain what this means?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello again guys i have recently found this code on another forum that i made the only problem that i am having is trying to explain what the code actually means

```
  var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","AmberLast.jpg"];
  var index = 0;

  function changeLights() {
    var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
    image.src = list[index];
    display.innerHTML = list[index]
```

Thanks For your help guys i hope i can hear your answers soon

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>

<img id="Red.jpg" src="Red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
  var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","AmberLast.jpg"];
  var index = 0;

  function changeLights() {
    var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
    image.src = list[index];
    display.innerHTML = list[index];

  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my entire code

Comment: by the ways this is a traffic light sequence

Comment: where is the rest of the function..?

Comment: Please consider asking such questions on a dedicated forum somewhere on the web. StackOverflow is about solving specific development questions, not about explaining coding basics.

Comment: However @HubertGrzeskowiak I'm sure this Forum has an open policy to any question's no matter if it is a development question or a basic question, in my case this is the Development of my GCSE Coursework.

Comment: @Ben, Why don't you execute the code yourself  in a browser  to understand the way the code works... This code is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","AmberLast.jpg"];
```

this is an **array** of names of image sources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
  var index = 0;
```

this a variable, it's called **index**, and has the value of **0** because you can target an element of an array (e.g Amber.jpg) using it's **index**. An array's index by default starts at **0** (zero based), so in the 'list' array above, the index of 0 (list[0]) will return 'Red.jpg'.

```
  function changeLights() {

    var image = document.getElementById('Red.jpg');
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
    image.src = list[index];
    display.innerHTML = list[index];

  }
```

This function selects the `<img>` tag with the ID of 'Red.jpg', and then sets it's src= to be **`index + 1 (= 1)`**, and then sets the inner HTML of the element with an ID of **display** to be **Amber.jpg (list[1]).**

The correct way to 'change lights' would instead be:

```
var list=["Red.jpg","Amber.jpg","Green.jpg","AmberLast.jpg"];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {

   var max = list.length - 1;
   var next = index += 1; 

   if(next > max) {
      next = 0; //start back at beginning
      index = 0;
   }  

   var image = document.getElementById('IDOFIMAGETAG'); //replace will correct ID of <img>

   image.src = list[next];

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response and change of the code however the code i Have used dose work and works well enough for what i am doing, however i will try your code and thank you for the input on my problem

Comment: as well as this in the html section above i have defined <img id="Red.jpg" src="Red.jpg">

Comment: if you decide to style the #Red.jpg in CSS, you will need to escape the period: #Red\.jpg . I wasn't aware that was a valid character in an ID! Cool